# How to run jsp pages in eclipse using tomcat server?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, jspx

![I want to run java program in a web browser. I installed tomcat and eclipse. but i am getting an error "Starting tomcatv7.0 server at local host". How to solve this error? Please help me. I have attached the error page:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Removed JS tag. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Comment: "*I want to run java program in a web browser.*" No you can't. A web browser can only interpret HTML, JavaScript (or other supported scripting languages) and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check whether your TOMCAT_HOME\bin contains bootstrap.jar. 
Second, go to your project build path and remove reference of bootstrap.jar and then try to run the application.

Regards,

Bipul Sinha

Answer (score 0):

it seems that u need to put bootstrap.jar in your tomcat's bin folder.

**upd**

try to delete tomcat's configured server from eclipse and add newone

**upd**
 goto Run -> Debug/Run Configuration -> Classpath tab and check your bootstrap.jar path is correct

Comment: oh thanks for your reply Mr.Secario .. How can i put bootstrap.jar in sytem? Can u pls tell more about that?

Comment: i have tried more than 5 times.. still its showing the same error.